# Not return anything from LISP/Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket, map-function

Basically, I would like to use map to do selection in a list like

```
(define tbl '(a b c d))
(map (lambda (item 'c) (if (eq? item 'c) item (...what in else?) )))
```

The result I want is

```
'(c)
```

I tried leave the else part empty, it complains that the else part is needed. 
I tried

```
(display "foo")
```

as else part and got

```
(#<void> #<void> c #<void>)
```

That is close.

Is there any way that I can use map to get '(c)? I know the recursive way, but I am wondering if map can do it as well. If not '(c), at least (# # c #) but not using the display hack to achieve a void type return value.

---

Comment: By the way: the `lambda` passed as parameter to `map` must receive a _single_ parameter, you're passing two and that won't work: `(item 'c)`

Comment: What interpreter are you using? my guess is Racket, but please confirm it

Comment: @ Óscar López, yes, it is Racket, but I hope the solution can be general

Comment: Use `filter` with `lambda`, that'll work in any interpreter I know.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez MIT Scheme says: `;Unbound variable: filter`.

Comment: @WillNess SRFI-1 then. That's the first interpreter I hear about that doesn't have `filter`, it should be standard though.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez well, it got *`keep-matching-items list predicate`* instead of *`filter predicate list`*. So it just uses another name for it. Anyway, question was about using `map` to filter, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Maybe that doesn't help you with your particular question, but whenever you're using an if-clause and don't know what to put in the else-part, I'd recommend using a when-clause. It's basically the same, it doesn't require an else-part, though. http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/when_unless.html

Answer (score 12):

You want to use [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._filter%29%29), not [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) - because the output list will potentially have less elements than the input list. All those `#<void>` values returned by `display` are there because `map` will always include a result in the output list, *even* for those elements we're not interested in.

```
(define tbl '(a b c d))

(filter (lambda (item) (eq? item 'c)) tbl)
=> '(c)
```

Equivalently, and a bit shorter:

```
(filter (curry eq? 'c) tbl)
=> '(c)
```

`map` is used when you want to do something to each of the elements in the input list, without discarding elements. On the other hand, `filter` is used for selecting *some* of the elements in the input list, those that evaluate to `#t` for a given predicate, and `filter` is available in most Scheme interpreters, if it's not available you can import [`SRFI-1`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FilteringPartitioning) or use the [reference implementation](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1-reference.scm).

There's no way to obtain `'(c)` using *only* `map` (it can be hacked using `map` plus `apply` or `remove*`, etc. but that's not the idea, is it?); if for some reason you *have to* use only `map` and don't mind returning a list with placeholders, here are a couple of alternatives:

```
(map (lambda (item) (if (eq? item 'c) item '%)) tbl) ; placeholder in else part
=> '(% % c %)

(map (lambda (item) (when (eq? item 'c) item)) tbl)  ; when has implicit #<void>
=> '(#<void> #<void> c #<void>)
```

Time for a little hacking. Using `map` plus [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) (as explained in @WillNess' answer), this has the advantage of working in any RxRS interpreter and is the most portable solution, because it uses standard procedures:

```
(apply append (map (lambda (item) (if (eq? item 'c) (list item) '())) tbl))
=> '(c)
```

Using `map` plus [`remove*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._remove%2A%29%29):

```
(remove* (list (void)) (map (lambda (item) (when (eq? item 'c) item)) tbl))
=> '(c)
```

For a change, a solution without `map` - using [`foldr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) instead:

```
(foldr (lambda (item a) (append (if (eq? item 'c) (list item) '()) a)) '() tbl)
=> '(c)
```

Of course, you can always implement your own version of `filter` using only standard procedures, this will also be portable across all RxRS interpreters:

```
(define (filter pred? lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         '())
        ((not (pred? (car lst)))
         (filter pred? (cdr lst)))
        (else
         (cons (car lst)
               (filter pred? (cdr lst))))))

(filter (lambda (item) (eq? item 'c)) tbl)
=> '(c)
```

Comment: Recommended reading for better understanding the `map` and `filter` procedures: [Sequences as Conventional Interfaces](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.3) in [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)

Comment: An alternative is (filter (cut eq? 'c <>) tbl) if your implementation lacks a curry function but supports SRFI-26. And for anyone who wants to dig deeper, both map and filter can be implemented using fold.

Comment: `#<void>`: yet another shard of `nil`, as broken in Scheme. What a cluster funk. "Somehow I preferred (CDR (ASSQ KEY A-LIST))" -- Ashwin Ram

Comment: For a more general answer: filter is standard procedure in [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) which is supported by most implementations, not just Racket. Those imlpementation that hasn't filter you may load it's [reference implementation](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1-reference.scm).

Comment: I think we have multiple answers on SO so that each can show its unique take on a given question. I get it that you want to provide the best all-encompassing answer to the OP, but I don't think we *must* have all-in-one answers here on SO... Your answer was: "use filter instead of map, or produce placeholders with map". My answer showed a solution with map and append. GoZoner's showed the use of removing primitives. Each answer should've been left to stand for itself, IMHO. Now it's confusing. What's the point in the other answers here, now? They're made a bit redundant, now... :) Just my 2cts

Answer (score 3):

The simple "standard" trick is

```
(apply append (map (lambda(x)(if (eq? x 'c) (list x) '())) '(a b c d)))
;Value 12: (c)
```

which returns `(c)`. The `apply append ... map` combo is known as `mapcan` in Common Lisp ("mapcan" for "map and concatenate"):

```
[1]> (mapcan #'(lambda(x)(if (eq x 'c) (list x))) '(a b c d))
(C)
```

MIT Scheme has this function too.

`apply append` flattens one level of its argument list, `(apply append '((a) () (c) ()))` **==** `(append '(a) '() '(c) '())` **-->** `(a c)`. Since empty lists disappear, it is useful for eliminating elements with `map`. This achieves the same effect as `filter` if you have one available (it is not in [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-15.html#%_chap_Temp_11), but it is in [SRFI1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FilteringPartitioning)).

It can be used for other effects too, like doubling:

```
[2]> (mapcan #'(lambda(x)(if (evenp x) (list x x))) '(1 2 3 4))
(2 2 4 4)
```

---

As an aside, `mapcan` is what's known as list monad's "bind" (with arguments flipped), and `(apply append ...)` as its "join" operation. Indeed as it must be for any monad, for lists too  `bind m f == join (map f m)`.

This is also the basis for e.g. Haskell's *list comprehensions*:

```
Prelude> [y | x<-[1,2,3,4], even x, y<-[x,x]]
[2,2,4,4]
```

Comment: The Racket equivalent of `mapcan` is `append-map`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your Scheme version/environment.  Assuming you only have the most basic Scheme, it is easy enough to implement something:

```
(define (choose-if pred list)
  (let choosing ((list list) (rslt '()))
    (if (null? list)
        (reverse rslt)
        (choosing (cdr list)
                  (if (pred (car list))
                      (cons (car list) rslt)
                      rslt)))))
```

and then related:

```
(define (choose item list)
  (choose-if (lambda (elt) (eq? item elt)) list))

(define (choose-if-not pred list)
  (choose-if (lambda (elt) (not (pred elt))) list))
```

and use:

```
> (choose 'c '(a b c d))
(c)
```

You also have the option to use low-level primitives like:

```
(define (choose item list)
  (remq #f (map (lambda (elt) (eq? item elt)) list)))
```

or

```
(define (choose item list)
   (remp (lambda (elt) (not (eq? item elt))) list))
```